# NullReferenceException when using MyListProperty.Add?

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception

```
 public List<string> myitems { get; set; }
    //Store All unique ID of this date in a list
    public void myitem(string Index)
    {
        myitems.Add(Index);
    }

  if (temp.Start == received)
            {

                scheduledItem scheduleditem = new scheduledItem(temp.Name, "1pm", "true");
                DataCollection.Add(scheduleditem);
                myitem(temp.UniqueID.ToString()); 
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Nothing");

            }
```

Any idea what went wrong with myitems.add(index); ?

Comment: Where is the `new List<string>`? It would explain the `null` ("lack of object")..

Answer (score 4):

You have to instantiate/initialize the `List<T>`.

```
 private List<string> _list = new List<string>();

 public List<string> myitems 
 { 
     get { return _list; }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You haven't actually initialized myitems. You need add this line of code somewhere, such as the constructor of your class

```
myitems = new List<string>();
```

Comment: OH! Okay , i'm starting to get the meaning of Initialize Thanks!